# R cannot be resolved - Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I know lots of people asked this question, but I've surfed all the questions and answers and still can't find the solutions for mine.

I've installed all the Android SDK Build-tools
[image]

and I don't have any errors in my res folder

[image]

I cleaned the project and restarted Eclipse several times, and R still not generated.
any solutions? Thank you !

[[SOLVED]] [[SOLUTION]] I found the solution for me was changing the target to

```
target=android-21
```

in the android.properties

Comment: Do you see any entries in problems tab of your eclipse? or a red cross symbol besides your project in project explorer?

Comment: Most common question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[SOLUTION]]
I found the solution for me was changing the target to

```
target=android-21
```

in the android.properties